# SQL getting status of a period

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm looking for a SQL solution for the following problem.
I want a list of employees who are more then 14 days sick in a row.

I've a sql table with the following:

```
First_name, Last_Name, INDIRECT_ID, SHIFT_DATE
John, Doe, Sick, 2016-01-01
John, Doe, Sick, 2016-01-02
John, Doe, working, 2016-01-03
John, Doe, Sick, 2016-01-04
John, Doe, Sick, 2016-01-05
etc.
```

I thought to do this by seeing if they are sick for 10x (2x 5 working days) in two weeks. But maybe there is a much simpler solution for it. But Now I'm also getting duplicate answers.

```
  select FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME
from (select t.*
             ,(select count(*)
              from LABOR_TICKET t2
              where t2.EMPLOYEE_ID = t.EMPLOYEE_ID and
                    t2.INDIRECT_ID = t.INDIRECT_ID and
                    t2.SHIFT_DATE >= t.SHIFT_DATE and 
                    t2.SHIFT_DATE < DATEADD(day, 14, t.SHIFT_DATE)) NumWithin14Days
      from LABOR_TICKET t 
      where SHIFT_DATE between '2016-01-01' and '2016-04-01'
     ) LABOR_TICKET 
    INNER JOIN
                      EMPLOYEE ON LABOR_TICKET.EMPLOYEE_ID = EMPLOYEE.ID

where NumWithin14Days >= 10 AND INDIRECT_ID = 'SICK'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,
First create all the 14 days intervals in between the From Date and To Date.
Then check the count of the 'Sick' is 14 in each interval for every employee.

```
DECLARE @ST_DATE    DATE='2016-01-01'
        ,@ED_DATE   DATE='2016-04-01'
;WITH CTE_DATE AS (

    SELECT  @ST_DATE AS ST_DATE,DATEADD(DAY,13,@ST_DATE) AS ED_DATE
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  DATEADD(DAY,1,ED_DATE),DATEADD(DAY,14,ED_DATE)
    FROM    CTE_DATE
    WHERE   DATEADD(DAY,14,ED_DATE) <= @ED_DATE
)
SELECT  FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME
FROM    CTE_DATE
    INNER JOIN LABOR_TICKET ON SHIFT_DATE BETWEEN ST_DATE AND ED_DATE
WHERE INDIRECT_ID = 'Sick'
GROUP BY FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME
HAVING   COUNT(*) >= 14
```

Comment: Thanks! It works fine in SQL Management Studio, but how can I implement this code into Microsoft SQL Server Report Builder, so the user can pick their start and end date. I've got this error:" Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part in column "St_DATE" of recursive "CTE_DATE"

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo code to give you idea for all employees

if you have a calendar table like below

```
create table dates
(
datetime date
)

insert into dates
select '2016-01-01'
union all
select '2016-01-02'
```

Now you can left join this with your main table like

```
select 
mt.firstname,dt.date,count(indirect_id)
 from 
datestable dt
left join
maintable mt
on mt.date=dt.date
and mt.indirect_id='sick'
group by mt.firstname,dt.date
having count(indirect_id)>=14
order by dt.date
```

Answer (score 0):

you should have thrown more sample data.

try this,(I am sure it will work with other sample data)few thing are just there to filter data.

```
declare @t table(First_name varchar(50), Last_Name varchar(50), INDIRECT_ID varchar(50), SHIFT_DATE date)
insert into @t values
('John', 'Doe', 'Sick', '2016-01-01')
,('John', 'Doe', 'Sick', '2016-01-02')
,('John','Doe','working','2016-01-03')
,('John', 'Doe', 'Sick', '2016-01-04')
,('John', 'Doe', 'Sick', '2016-01-05')

declare @name varchar(50)='John'
declare @month int=1
;With CTE as
(
  select top 1 First_name,Last_Name,SHIFT_DATE,1 rn  from @T where First_name=@name 
    and INDIRECT_ID='Sick' order by SHIFT_DATE
    union all
    select  t.First_name,t.Last_Name,t.SHIFT_DATE, rn+1  from @T t 
    inner join cte c on t.First_name=c.First_name
where  INDIRECT_ID='Sick' 
    and t.SHIFT_DATE=DATEADD(day,1,c.SHIFT_DATE)
    and t.SHIFT_DATE<='2016-01-31'
)

select * from CTE where rn>=14
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @t table(First_name varchar(50), Last_Name varchar(50), INDIRECT_ID varchar(50), SHIFT_DATE date)
insert into @t values
('John', 'Doe', 'Sick',  '2016-01-01')
,('John', 'Doe', 'Sick', '2016-01-02')
,('John','Doe','working','2016-01-03')
,('John', 'Doe', 'Sick', '2016-04-04')
,('John', 'Doe', 'Sick', '2016-05-05')

select  s.*
        ,u.* 
        ,Sickdays = 
        case 
        when s.indirect_id = 'Sick' and u.indirect_id = 'Sick' then datediff(dd,u.shift_date,s.shift_date)
        else 0
        end
from 
(
select  t.*,
        row_number() over(partition by last_name,first_name order by shift_date desc)  rn
from    @t t
) s
join    
(select t.*,
        row_number() over(partition by last_name,first_name order by shift_date desc)  rn
from    @t t
) u on s.last_name = u.last_name and s.first_name = u.first_name  and s.rn = u.rn - 1
where 
        case 
        when s.indirect_id = 'Sick' and u.indirect_id = 'Sick' then datediff(dd,u.shift_date,s.shift_date)
        else 0
        end > 13
```

Comment: Please note dates are localised to UK ie yyyymmdd in my test data. Needless to say it would be much safer if you had an employee id to join on and in the real world you would probalably have to report sickness over working days which is not so easy.